# Impresspages: site logo padding on bottom, in 'Air' theme; how to remove?

Tags: css, padding, impresspages

I have searched most of the css files, changed the logo padding in theme.css, but I cannot remove the padding on the bottom of the site logo. There seems to be a 5px padding at the bottom. Is there a way to remove this? Thanks.

Edit: Here is the code in Air theme's, theme.css file, where I can only find logo css references. Thanks again.

```css
.logo {
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  padding: 0px;    
    
}
.logo a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Cinzel', 'Arvo', serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/abkoc.png][1]

Comment: You should provide some of your relevant code aswell.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Impresspages but if you're trying to overwrite the theme's css with a custom css try 
`.logo{
padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}`

Comment: Thanks for support, but it doesn't remove padding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not a padding. The issues comes from browser's interpretation of img in `<a>` tag. By default all browsers render image with 3px bottom space (and it's not a margin nor padding; just an empty space).

There are 2 ways to remove it:

1. Float image
2. Display image as a block

In this case I'd choose the first option.

```
.logo img {
    float: left;
}
```